# reading the running config file from a network device

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, cisco-jtapi

Is there any way to read the running configuration file from a network device (cisco ios/ juniper junos) in a properly formatted type say for eg as an XML file?

Basically I need to get all the attributes and its values in a config file. I am using "expect" to read the config file. I would have to write a parser to get the attributes from the config file.

I was wondering if there would be already an implementation of this which I can re-use?
Is there any SDK that can be used to parse the config file, or even better , directly interact with the device and get the data in a standard format?

Kindly guide.

Thanks 
Sunil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Juniper in configuration mode:

`show | display xml`

For Cisco IOS I've never made this, but you can try to use ODMSpec:
http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios-xml/ios/xmlpi/command/xmlpi-cr-book.pdf
http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/net_mgmt/enhanced_device_interface/2.2/developer/guide/progodm.html

I'm not sure, that it works with running-config.

Answer (score 0):

In ios devices, it is

```
show run | format
```

This would give the result in an xml format